# Como puedo implementar un observer con Voyager en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

quisiera saber si alguien me podria dar una mano con el paquete admin Voyager de Laravel. Estoy tratando de usar un observer para el modelo User, sin embargo el sistema no detecta ningun evento del Observer, intento enviar un mail cuando se cree un user en la vista de admin de voyager.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los modelos que tengo fuera de las rutas de voyager si oyen los eventos sin problema.
Adjunto captura del Observer que quiero implementar cuando se creen usuarios, intente tambien probar con el modelo que genera voyager pero ni siquiera entra al metodo created.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El observer esta registrado en el EventServiceProvider

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por favor no pongas el código como imágenes. Estaría bien también que añadas el link al paquete que añadiste. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, estoy usando observers para aplicar a mi modelo User, estoy haciendo uso del paquete Voyager (https://voyager.devdojo.com/)  cuando el paquete se instala el modelo  User extiende de clases de Voyager. Mi problema es que no logro capturar los eventos de created, deleted, updated...  con este paquete.

Comment: Si lo de la imagen con codigo cai en cuenta despues de formular la pregunta, perdon! es mi primera pregunta en la comunidad.